# How to use multiple pic from array struct into apart cell in the swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have two `UITableViewController` and one `UIViewController`.
In the first `UITableViewController` I have 2 rows and if I select row 1 then it must go to the `UIViewController`. Otherwise if I select row 2 then it must go to `UITableViewController` 2

I could do that by this code and segue in the story board:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("ViewController 1", sender: self)
    } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("TableViewController 2", sender: self)
    }
}
```

now this run normally and no problem!
My problem is in the `UIViewController` where I have an `UIImage` and I can't add any pic from array struct in this UIImage
My struct and array are:

```
struct Files {
    var name : String
    var filename : String
    var notes : String
}

var file = [Files]()

let newfile = Files(name:"" , filename:"" , notes: "")
file.append(newfile)
```

and my `UIViewController` code is:

```
@IBOutlet weak var currentimage: UIImageView!
var currentfile : Files?

override func viewDidLoad() 
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    currentimage.image = UIImage(named: currentfile!.filename)
}
```

I don't know whats my problem that when i select in row 1 my iphone crashed

you have may thanks if help me :)

Comment: Where are you instantiating the Files struct in your code?

Comment: Can you report the error message that you get on crash?

Comment: @ezcoding i add a new swift file and define struct in it

Comment: @lucky_starss error message is : fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

Comment: The only posted line which can cause this type of error is this `currentimage.image = UIImage(named: currentfile!.filename)` because `currentfile` is nil. The @Levi answer solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you are posting a crash, it is ususally usefull to say what is the exception, and at which line it crashes.

Your`currentFile` is `nil`, it was never initialized and you are forcing an unwrap on it (with `!`), that is why your app is crashing. Your `viewDidLoad` should look something like:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    currentfile = Files(name:"somename" , filename:"somefilename" , notes: "")
    currentimage.image = UIImage(named: currentfile!.filename)
}
```

And whenever you are not sure about an optional being `nil`, you should not use forced unwrapping. This would have prevented your crash:

```
if let unwrappedCurrentFile = currentFile {
    currentimage.image = UIImage(named: unwrappedCurrentFile.filename)
}
```